# Flutter return snackbar on successfully posting data to API

Tags: flutter, try-catch, future, snackbar

I am trying to display a snackbar for both success and failure of posting data to an API. The bar appears to be appearing which is great, but it seems be showing the success even when the data should fail. I am expecting that the then only renders if a card is actually successfully written back to stripe, otherwise to use the catch and surface the error

This is the future

```
static Future<Payment> createPayment(context, Payment payment) async {
    final response = await http
        .post(
      Uri.parse('$stripeRef/payment/credit-card/new/${payment.userId}'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        // 'card_number': payment.cardNumber,
        'card_number': payment.cardNumber,
        'expiry_month': payment.expMonth,
        'expiry_year': payment.expYear,
        'cvv': payment.cvv
      }),
    )
        .then((response) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
        'Successfully Added New Payment',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      )));
    }).catchError((error) => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to update because of $error'))));
```

Comment: The 'then' state does not always mean success. That success means that request received from server. In the response there would be data if request succeeded or error message if request failed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add some validation in response and on basis of the validation on response showSnackBar whether failed or success.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).